# Dockerfileで環境変数PATHが設定されない

Tags: docker, rbenv

Dockerを利用して、仮想環境でrbenvを導入しようとしていますが`rbenv install`の部分でPATHが通っていないとエラーが出てしまいます。
Dockerfileは下記の通りです。

```
FROM centos:centos7

# gitをインストール
RUN yum -y install git

# rbenvをインストール
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN exec $SHELL -l
RUN echo $PATH
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN ["rbenv", "install", "-v", "2.2.3"]
RUN ["rbenv", "rehash"]
RUN ["rbenv",  "global",  "2.2.3"]
```

build実行時のログは下記の通りです。

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 1 : FROM centos:centos7
 ---> 0f0be3675ebb
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> da0472c69ce1
Step 3 : RUN yum -y install git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24b5366b0d4d
Step 4 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1859d24d8942
Step 5 : RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 940d5514a25c
Step 6 : RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 747ad3b73095
Step 7 : RUN exec $SHELL -l
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f2a32ad3625c
Step 8 : RUN echo $PATH
 ---> Running in 13448ff76c37
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
 ---> e4cf92d0f3e4
Removing intermediate container 13448ff76c37
Step 9 : RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
 ---> Running in 1309b521d2e2
Cloning into '/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build'...
 ---> 4c892315923a
Removing intermediate container 1309b521d2e2
Step 10 : RUN rbenv install -v 2.2.3-p173
 ---> Running in da7cc2ecf7e1
exec: "rbenv": executable file not found in $PATH
Container command not found or does not exist.
```

途中echo $PATHで確認していますがやはりPATHが通っていないようです。
アドバイスいただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ENVを使いましょう＃http://qiita.com/TakashiOshikawa/items/2b8974c242a7054e0be5

Comment: ENVを使うと環境変数を設定できることは分かりました。ありがとうございます。そこで、`ENV PATH $HOME/.rvenv/bin:$PATH`と設定を追加しましたがやはり`/bin/sh: rbenv: command not found`と表示されてしまいます。環境変数は`/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`となっているので設定されているようです。

Comment: $HOME を使うのはお勧めしません。

Answer (score 1):

- Dockerfile で環境変数を設定するのは RUN ではなく ENV を使います。RUN だとその RUN が終わるところまでしかその変更が反映されません。
- `~/.bash_profile` は non-login shell では読み込まれず、また各 RUN でも読み込まれません。今回のように環境変数の設定を書きたいのであればやはり ENV を使います。
- Docker イメージとして使う場合、rbenv のバージョン管理機能は不要では無いでしょうか。[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65542/19110)のように ruby-build だけを使う方法で充分そうです。