# Docker で Ruby (rbenv) のインストールがうまくいかない

Tags: ruby, docker, rbenv

Docker上(CentOS7)でrubyをインストールしています。

Dockerfile内の以下のコマンドで実行は正常にされたものの、

```
RUN rbenv install 2.7.1
```

ビルド後、コンテナのbashに入って`ruby -v`で確認すると、

```
bash: ruby: command not found
```

正常にインストールされていない状態で何が原因なのかわからない状況です。
パスの設定か？と思いましたが、下記のソースコードの通り特に問題はない気がしています。

解決策を教えていただけると助かります。

## ソースコード

~/.bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv"
export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
eval "$(rbenv init --no-rehash -)"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7.7.1908

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y git tzdata libxml2-devel.x86_64 libcurl-devel.x86_64 gcc-c++.x86_64 glibc-devel.x86_64 mariadb-devel.x86_64 ImageMagick.x86_64 bzip2 make which

RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git /usr/local/rbenv
RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git /usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

RUN echo 'export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init --no-rehash -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
ENV PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN ./usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/install.sh

RUN rbenv install 2.7.1
RUN rbenv global 2.7.1
```

dokcer-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  rails:
    build: .
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    command: bash
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

複数のバージョンの `ruby` を使いわける必要がないのなら、 `rbenv` は不要で `ruby-build` だけを使うのがオススメです。

```
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build && PREFIX=/usr/local ./ruby-build/install.sh && rm -rf ruby-build
RUN ruby-build 2.7.1 /usr/local
```

のように `ruby-build` と `ruby` を `/usr/local` にインストールしてしまえば `PATH` を追加する必要もなくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
これはビックリしました。確かにおっしゃる通りです。
今回はバージョンを使い分けることもないので、これでいきたいと思います。

Answer (score 4):

コンテナの中でPATHを通すときはbash profileなどを使うのではなくDockerfileの中でENV命令を使います。

```
ENV RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"'
```

といった具合でやってみると良さそうです。

ちなみに、CentOS上で動かしたいという明確な理由がない限りは、Rubyを動かすだけであれば公式のイメージでもよさそうですね！

Comment: 確かに適切な書き方ではなかったです。
「あーこんなところでつまずいていたのか...」と思ってしまいました。ありがとうございます。
本当はRailsをCentOS上で動かすのが目的でしたが、質問をわかりやすくするためにrubyのインストールに絞りました。

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile` は Bash がログインシェルとして起動された際に読み込まれるファイルですが、今回の Dockerfile によって作られたイメージに `docker run -it` で入っても Bash は non-login shell として呼び出されているので `~/.bash_profile` を読み込みません。このため `rbenv init` などが実行されておらず、`ruby` コマンドが PATH から見えていません。

Docker で Ruby を使いたい場合、OS に拘らないのであれば公式イメージの [ruby](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) を使い、CentOS に拘るのであれば `yum` でバージョン指定しつつインストールするのがとりあえずは良いでしょう。rbenv を使いたくなるのは、`yum` で提供されていないような新しいバージョンの Ruby を使いたい場合でしょうか。

rbenv を質問文のように使う場合、`~/.bash_profile` は使わず、環境変数は `ENV` で更新し、`rbenv init` は `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` に書く方法があります。

```
ENV RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv"
ENV PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init --no-rehash -)"' > /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
```

※ CentOS 7 の場合、`/etc/profile.d/*.sh` は login shell として起動したとき `/etc/profile` から読み込まれる他、non-login interactive shell として起動したとき `/etc/bashrc` から読み込まれます。

ただこれでも non-login non-interactive shell として実行された場合には反映されません。

Docker イメージとして使う場合 Ruby のバージョンを後から変更しないのが普通な気がするので、そうであれば eval するのではなく `rbenv init` の内容を確かめて ENV 等で設定したり、[Kazuhiro NISHIYAMA さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65542/19110)のように ruby-build だけ使う方が良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
~/.bash_profileを読み込まないのは初めて知りました。
詳しいご説明、大変助かります。メモしておきます。
本当はRailsをCentOS上で動かすのが目的でしたが、質問をわかりやすくするためにrubyのインストールに絞りました。